# critical runtime error after upgrading application with .NET assembly dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am upgrading an application and running into some issues with it. 
Now the old application was version 1.0 and loading a depedency assembly A at version 2.1.1 The assembly is present in application local directory.
I am upgrading the new application to version 2.0 that will load assembly A version 1.0.1 which is present in its application local directory. I've checked application references using ISpy and confirmed the new application references A version 1.0.1

But when I start the new application (v 2.0), it is still trying to load assembly version 2.1.1 and failing. I checked the app.config, machine.config and GAC and there is no redirection for version of assembly A. I also checked fusion log files but don't see any redirection. All I see is the fusion log is that application prebinds A at version 2.1.1 and hence fails to set up the assembly present in its local directory.

Is there something I am missing here? What could be the possible reasons for application still referencing the older assembly at runtime?

**Update:** Using some tools, I realized the the older assembly is being  referenced from a native DLL that is referenced by my application, but I don't know which third party DLL is that, and the application loads a ton of them. The fusion log confirms it by logging "Calling assembly : (Unknown)." for the missing assembly.

Now my next step is to find which dll is referencing the wrong assembly and fix that. Now the problem is that ILSpy tool doesn't show the native DLLs references, and DLLDepends tool does not show the assemblies references, so I am not able to link the two.

thanks

Comment: A .NET assembly that is used by native code is usually a [ComVisible] assembly.  Found from keys in the registry.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon if you have no idea.

Comment: thanks for the info. But I don't see any of my assemblies registered. I did a search of their names in the registry and found nothing. Is there another way COM dll could reference the older version of assembly?

Comment: Sure.  What did ProcMon tell you?

Comment: Actually ProcMon is quite useful. Thanks for pointing it out. I think I need to re-register some .NET Assemblies using regasm. So I need to do some registry searching to find which ones are causing problems. It is a mess at the moment. Hope to get this straightened out on Monday. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Since the library your trying to reference is supposed to be apart of the GAC; you may want to try:

1. Control Panel
2. Small Icons(Administrative Tools)
3. Event Viewer
4. Application

Windows itself should throw an exception with some particular details it's attempting to reference when it has an error.  Especially if it's apart of the GAC.  It was more helpful for me to hone in *mscoree.dll* and *mscorelib.dll* libraries fairly easy.  Granted those clients that I used that for had corrupt framework; but Event Viewer told me the exact library that it had an issue with.

You may want to try that.  Not sure which library; but keep in mind this is usually beneficial to libraries that are found within the `%windir%/Assembly` folder.  Hope that helps.